# How can I wrap JSON object with a parent object or field?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, reactjs

I need to convert the format of my JSON string called `filter_by_address` to have a `final output` like this:

```
{
  "input": {
    "citybooks": [
      {
        "city": "Moss Beach",
      },
      {
        "city": "Half Moon Bay",
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

What I currently did I is the code below:

```js
var filtered = '[{"author":"Ernest Hemingway","title":"Snow White","address":"Sydney","link":{"url":"https://www.loremipsum.com"},"booktype":{"type":"Science Fiction"}},{"author":"J.K. Rowling","title":"Harry Potter","address":"Sydney","link":{"url":"https://www.loremipsum.com"},"booktype":{"type":"Textbook"}}]';
var books_data_array = JSON.parse(filtered);
var new_objects = [];

//console.log(books_data_array);

for (var i = 0; i < books_data_array.length; i++) {
  //console.log(books_data_array[i]["author"]);

  var new_object = {
    "citybooks": [{
      "city": "address",
    }]
  }

  new_objects.push(new_object);

}

console.log(new_objects);
```

Something is still missing with my code. I need to wrap all the objects returned by `citybooks` field in an `"input"`.

Comment: Sorry I'm a little confused, what is the output that you expect?

Comment: @German Look for the `final output` word above. That is the output I am expecting

Comment: Thanks, I suggested with reduce, it is a great array function like map.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `map` to loop thru the array and construct the desired structure.

```js
var filtered = '[{"author":"Ernest Hemingway","title":"Snow White","address":"Sydney","link":{"url":"https://www.loremipsum.com"},"booktype":{"type":"Science Fiction"}},{"author":"J.K. Rowling","title":"Harry Potter","address":"Sydney","link":{"url":"https://www.loremipsum.com"},"booktype":{"type":"Textbook"}}]';
var books_data_array = JSON.parse(filtered);

var new_objects = {
  input: {
    citybooks: books_data_array.map(o => ({city: o.address})),
  }
}

console.log(new_objects);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also try with reduce, but it is up to you.

```
  var filtered = '[{"author":"Ernest Hemingway","title":"Snow White","address":"Sydney","link":{"url":"https://www.loremipsum.com"},"booktype":{"type":"Science Fiction"}},{"author":"J.K. Rowling","title":"Harry Potter","address":"Sydney","link":{"url":"https://www.loremipsum.com"},"booktype":{"type":"Textbook"}}]';
  const books_data_array = JSON.parse(filtered);
  var new_objects = [];

const filtered = books_data_array.reduce((cur, acc) => {
    const currEl = cur['input'].cityBooks;
    const addr = acc.address;
    const res = [...currEl, addr];
    return {input: {cityBooks: res}}
}, {input: {cityBooks:[]}})

console.log(filtered);
```